# Does this LDAP filter work?

Tags: windows, filter, active-directory, ldap

I want to query LDAP for all users in a specific OU (call it OU = Anberlin)

This is my current approach:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(memberOf=OU=Anberlin, DC=Domain, DC=local)( !(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))
```

That should get all the enabled users in that OU right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't. The memberOf attribute stores the list of groups the object is a member of.

All LDAP searches have a base DN value that you can pass as well as the query. Usually it's the whole domain, but if you set the base DN to your OU, then you will only get results from that OU.

So this is what you'd use for your search:

Base DN: `OU=Anberlin,DC=Domain,DC=local`

Query: `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)( !(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))`

Comment: I apologize if this seems dense but I am not seeing how that Base DN is getting used by the query. To my eye (novice eye) it looks like we are just querying for all enabled users in the domain.

Comment: How are making the query? In code? If so, which language?

Comment: I'm doing this in a UI for SharePoint. This is my start point

(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)( !(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))

It is currently getting all the enabled users on the domain. I am trying to query for just a specific OU.

Comment: It must be hiding the base DN from you then. Or maybe it's calling it something else. Is there a 'Populate Containers' option? (I'm doing random searches online to find screenshots - I don't exactly know what you're looking at)

Comment: It could also be called "Search base"

Comment: Yes, there is a "Populate Containers" option. And now you got me thinking that the answer is probably to toy with this instead of the query string.

Thanks for the assistance. I appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, from what I see in screenshots online, that seems like it will let you filter by OU. Glad I could help.